# How to add a load more button to load next 50 requests from axios call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Right now my code is below, I have the start of the URL in my proxy:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class BeerList extends Component {
  state = {
    beers: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(`/beers/?key=6f8f96d8bd670a389ec963899a8e958d`)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.setState({ beers: res.data.data });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.beers.map(beer => (
          <li key={beer.id}>{beer.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
export default BeerList;
```

I am getting the first 50 items from this api, but want to display a load more button at the bottom to load the next 50 and so on. How is this possible?

Comment: Is your API supporting some kind of pagination?

Comment: Here is the complete URL: http://api.brewerydb.com/v2/beers/?key=6f8f96d8bd670a389ec963899a8e958d, it includes page numbers and I believe it increments every 50 items per page

Comment: What parameter do you add to that url to tell it what the start and end numbers are? `myurl.com/data?start=51&end=100`?

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](https://brewerydb.com/developers/docs/endpoint/beer-index), you can pass a `p` query parameter to ask for a specific page.

First, you could isolate the fetching from your component with a simple function (in the same file or another file).

```
async function fetchBeerList(key, { page }) {
  return axios
    .get("https://sandbox-api.brewerydb.com/v2/", {
      params: {
        key,
        p: page
      }
    })
    // Pre-parse Axios' `data` nesting.
    .then(({ data }) => data);
}
```

Then, the component could look something like this:

```
class BeerList extends Component {
  state = {
    beers: [],
    currentPage: 0,
    numberOfPages: 0
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    // Reusing the same callback as our button
    this.fetchMoreBeers();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // Simple flag to avoid state updates if the component was unmounted before
    // our fetch had the time to finish.
    this._unmounted = true;
  }

  fetchMoreBeers = () => {
    const { beerId } = this.props;
    const { currentPage } = this.state;

    this.setState({ isFetching: true });

    fetchBeerList(beerId, { page: currentPage + 1 }).then(
      this.updateBeers,
      this.onFailure
    );
  };

  onFailure = err => {
    // avoid updating state on an unmounted component
    if (this._unmounted) return;

    this.setState({ isFetching: false, err });
  };

  updateBeers = ({ currentPage, numberOfPages, data }) => {
    // avoid updating state on an unmounted component
    if (this._unmounted) return;

    this.setState(({ beers }) => ({
      isFetching: false,
      beers: beers.concat(data),
      currentPage,
      numberOfPages
    }));
  };

  render() {
    const { beers, isFetching, currentPage, numberOfPages } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {beers.map(beer => (
            <li key={beer.id}>{beer.name}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
        {!isFetching && currentPage < numberOfPages && (
          <button type="button" onClick={this.fetchMoreBeers}>
            See more
          </button>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The button only shows up if the number of pages is higher than the current page index, or if we're not already fetching.

It also assumes you're receiving the `beerId` as a prop.

```
<BeerList beerId="6f8f96d8bd670a389ec963899a8e958d" />
```

---

To minimize the noise in JSX, I prefer to destructure everything I need.

```
const { beers, isFetching, currentPage, numberOfPages } = this.state;
```

To enforce this in projects I work on, we use [`react/destructuring-assignment` eslint's react plugin rule](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/destructuring-assignment.md).

In addition to readability improvements, it ensures that no context nightmares can happen with something like `this.props.onClick()` using the wrong `this` and messing with immutable props.

---

[Read more about `this._unmounted`.](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html)